# how to split text file vertically

Tags: command-line

How to split `log.txt` into `timeline.txt` and `action.txt` using the **shortest** bash  one-line command?

`tee <log.txt >(cut -d' ' -f1 >timeline.txt) >(cut -d' ' -f2- >action.txt)`

But it's too long, and duplication of `cut`.

log.txt

```
[00:00] Do A
[02:24] Do B
[16:12] Do C
... ...
```

timelime.txt

```
[00:00]
[02:24]
[16:12]
... ...
```

action.txt

```
Do A
Do B
Do C
... ...
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this with "the shortest bash one-line command"? If you're doing it a lot, put it into a function. Fewer lines of code are only better if you're doing one thing per line.

Comment: It's not just about typing, but about performance. Two cut invocations is duplication of effort. I don't know how much difference that makes in practice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `cut`:

```
$ cut -f1  -d' ' log.txt > timelime.txt
$ cut -f2- -d' ' log.txt > action.txt
```

I'm assuming that you have a single space after the "]" and that you're on a Unix-ish system.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print $1 > "timelime.txt"; $1=""; print > "action.txt"}' log.txt
```

Comment: If that leaves a stray space at the beginning of your `action.txt` lines (my `awk` does) then you could `print substr($0, 2) > "action.txt"` to take care of it. There might be better ways but my awk-Fu isn't the strongest.

Comment: I actually like your `awk` solution (with the `substr` fix) better than my `cut` approach. I think it makes sense to change your mind again and accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In the question, you express concern about calling cut twice; here's a method that only reads the input once:

```
sed 'h; s/[^ ]* //; waction.txt
x; s/ .*//; wtimeline.txt' log.txt
```